# Why do old questions pop up from time to time?

Tags: discussion, questions

Occasionally when I click the `/questions` link I'll see questions from long ago float up to the top. I only see it from time to time but I was wondering what caused it. The latest one is [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/tracking-down-where-disk-space-has-gone-on-linux) which was at the top of that page for me and is from clear back in 2008.

**EDIT:**

Shortly after posting I'm seeing where it was migrated just a few minutes ago. I'm going to assume this is the likely cause of it.

Answer (score 6):

The [community user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) also pushes old posts back to the front page. See its profile:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like:
>
>    * Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention

Answer (score 1):

If they have been edited, they appear on the front page, of course. Additionally, if the questions do not have an accepted answer, they are occasionally brought back to the front page, presumably so as to get them some attention.